# Sorting values (for loop)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a simple nucleotide counter in python 2.7 and at one of the methods I wrote I'd like to print the g,c,a,t values **sorted by the number of times they show up in the gene sheet.**
what could be the better way to do that? Thanks in advance!

```
 def counting(self):
    gene = open("BRCA1.txt", "r")
    g = 0
    a = 0
    c = 0
    t = 0
    gene.readline()
    for line in gene:
        line = line.lower()
        for char in line:
            if char == "g":
                g += 1
            if char == "a":
                a += 1
            if char == "t":
                t += 1
            if char == "c":
                c += 1
    print "number of g\'s: %r" % str(g)
    print "number of c\'s: %r" % str(c)
    print "number of d\'s: %r" % str(a)
    print "number of t\'s: %r" % str(t)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class.

```
from collections import Counter
def counting(self):
    with open("BRCA1.txt", "r") as gene:
        nucleotide_counts = Counter(char for line in gene for char in line.lower().strip())
    for (nucleotide, count) in nucleotide_counts.most_common():
        print "number of %s's: %d" % (nucleotide, count)
```

If your lines might contain things besides nucleotides, this should work:

```
from collections import Counter
def counting(self):
    nucleotides = frozenset(('g', 'a', 't', 'c'))
    with open("BRCA1.txt", "r") as gene:
        nucleotide_counts = Counter(char for line in gene for char in line.lower() if char in nucleotides)
    for (nucleotide, count) in nucleotide_counts.most_common():
        print "number of %s's: %d" % (nucleotide, count)
```

That version doesn't need `strip` because newlines and other whitespace would be excluded by checking set membership.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class.

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(char for line in gene for char in line.lower() )
for char, count in counter.most_common():
    print "number of %s\'s: %d" % (char, count)
```